# Negative semi-definiteness stability

Tags: stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I am working on the stability of a system for the estimation $z_i$ predicted from x using the basic observer design. The relation is as follows:
\begin{equation}
z_i = \frac{\eta_i }{k_i}(\dot{x} - \dot{z}_i),
\label{eq:tro_1} 
\end{equation}
Based on the Lyapunov stability theory, I selected the Lyapunov function candidate as:
\begin{equation}
V(z_i) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z_i - \dot{x}\right),
\label{eq:tro_5} 
\end{equation}
The derivative of $\dot{V}(z_i)$ gives:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\dot{V}(z_i) &= \left(z_i - \dot{x}\right)\dot{z}_i\\
        &=\left(z_i - \dot{x}\right)\dot{x} - \frac{k_i}{\eta_i}({z_i} - \dot{x})\\
        &= \left(z_i - \dot{x}\right)^2 \left(1 - \frac{k_i}{\eta_i}\right)\\,
\label{eq:tro_6} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Can I then say that: for $\frac{k_i}{\eta_i}>0$, $\dot{V}(z_i)$ is negative semi-definite (not necessarily negative definite) as $V(z_i)$ will be decreasing?

I am working on this and I ama somehow stuck and want to be sure my concept is correct.